# Sort an array of date ranges in typeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
    Array(6) [
    "10-2022 - 12-2022", 
    "08-2022 - 09-2022", 
    "07-2023 - 10-2023", 
    "04-2022 - 07-2022", 
    "01-2023 - 06-2023", 
    "01-2022 - 03-2022" ]
```

I want to sort this array of date ranges to show the latest date range at the beginning of the array. Having some trouble because the dates are in string format.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `Array.sort` can take a [`compare` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#parameters) as a parameter so you need to implement one which works with your input. Also, be aware that `Array.sort` mutates the array, which will make you run into problems with React if you don't make a copy beforehand.

Comment: I tried `Array.sort` but had no luck. I think its because it takes a range of dates as the argument ` "10-2022 - 12-2022"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this utility function:

```js
const arr = [
    "10-2022 - 12-2022", 
    "08-2022 - 09-2022", 
    "07-2023 - 10-2023", 
    "07-2023 - 11-2023", 
    "04-2022 - 07-2022", 
    "01-2023 - 06-2023", 
    "01-2022 - 03-2022"
];

const getYearMonth = (date) => {
    const dateSplit = date.split('-');
  if (dateSplit.length < 2) return '';
  return dateSplit[1] + '-' + dateSplit[0];
}

const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
    const aSplit = a.split(' - ');
  const bSplit = b.split(' - ');
  const aYearMonthStart = getYearMonth(aSplit[0]);
  const bYearMonthStart = getYearMonth(bSplit[0]);
  // Sort decreasing by start
  if (aYearMonthStart > bYearMonthStart) return -1;
  if (aYearMonthStart < bYearMonthStart) return 1;
  // Sort decreasing by end date if start date equal
  const aYearMonthEnd = getYearMonth(aSplit[1]);
  const bYearMonthEnd = getYearMonth(bSplit[1]);
  if (aYearMonthEnd > bYearMonthEnd) return -1;
  if (aYearMonthEnd < bYearMonthEnd) return 1;
  // Equal dates
  return 0;
})

console.log(sortedArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Array.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a))
```